# Powershell script for outputting filename (+extension) and full path separated by ",", to .txt-file in a directory

Tags: powershell, path

I need to get all filenames + extenstions and path to those files in a directory separated by `;`.

If I have a directory `C:\Files\` with files: `file1.pdf`, `file2.docx`, `file3.pdf`, the resulting .txt file would look like this:

```
file1.pdf ; C:\Files\
file2.docx ; C:\Files\
file3.pdf ; C:\Files\
```

I haven't been able to use cmdlet `Get-ChildItem` to get both file name and path.

I have tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *Path* -Name >> files.txt
```

Haven't been able to figure out how to add path separated by filename with ";"

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `-Name` switch - and then instead use `Select-Object` to select the relevant subset of properties from each file, and `Export-Csv` (or `ConvertTo-Csv`) to create the output format:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File |Select-Object Name,DirectoryName |Export-Csv path\to\export.txt -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Also `-NoHeader -UseQuotes Never` to the `Export-Csv` if, for whatever reason, one doesn't want headers and the values being encapsulated into quotes, as implied by OP.

But keeping headers and quoted values make the file easier to import again later in powershell or other programs so I'd keep them if possible.

Comment: I think you want to use  `DirectoryName` rather than `Directory`...

Comment: @KeithMiller You're absolutely right (although it incidentally works as intended here because `Export-Csv` stringifies the property)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following command. You can loop through the files and output a `.txt` file with the name of the file + the directory.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Files" | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Name) ; $($_.Directory.FullName)" } | Out-File -FilePath "files.txt"
```

Output:

```
file1.pdf ; C:\Files
file2.docx ; C:\Files
file3.pdf ; C:\Files
```

`$_.Directory.FullName` gets the full path name for you.

Comment: You can also use `$_.DirectoryName`.